# Is there anything significant about this seemingly arbitrary constant?

Tags: summation

$$\sum^N\frac{1}{n^n} = 1 / 1^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^3 + 1/4^4 \ + \dotsb= 1.291285997... \text{ for }\ N \to \infty $$

Maybe this is related to the Riemann-Zeta function? I'm taking a wild guess.

Comment: Read about [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore's_dream)

Comment: Woa. I just discovered an identity without even knowing it. +1.

Comment: It's a particular value of the Sophomore's dream function : $Sphd(-1,1)$ , from Eq.7:4 in "The Sophomore's dream function" : http://fr.scribd.com/doc/34977341/Sophomore-s-Dream-Function

Answer (score 1):

Hans Zauber pointed out that this is part of an identity called "sophomore's dream" that was discovered by Bernoulli.

Comment: Well, to be precise, this is just the number involved in the identity. It's not an identity without both side of the equals sign. :)